# Parse .md file with php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, parsing, laravel-5, markdown

Is there a way to parse an .md file with php or javascript for code snippets.

My scenario is the following:

I have been migrating an old system (php4) to a Laravel Framework(php7) which needed Schema updates. All of this updates I made it manually( I know I could used migrations but the table structure is quite extensive and I want to persevere the old datas in my new system) and I made a history of changes over mysql updates in a Changelog.md.

Now I try to make an automised migration on schema check if matches some negative rules on table columns with a middleware. For example if Table X does not contain  columns Y,Z .. than my system is obsoleted and needs an update of schema and I redirect to dedicated Controller.

no I want to read the changelog with changes let it run this mysql updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using http://parsedown.org/

```
$Parsedown = new Parsedown();
echo $Parsedown->text('Hello _Parsedown_!'); # prints: <p>Hello<em>Parsedown</em>!</p>
```

You can install it for Laravel easily : https://github.com/parsedown/laravel